# Increasing size of VM (VMWare) not working

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware

So this seems rather odd but I'm having a hard time just simply expanding my C: on my VM. I'm using VMWare. IN my settings I was able to increase the disc size to 130GB (from 75 or so). I go into the VM, Administrative tools > Computer Management > Storage and I see 55 GB Free space but the extend volume on my C is greyed out. How can I simply just take the 55 free and put it on the C drive?

[image]

Comment: to extend this way it has to be continuous space. you should probably use a third party boot image for partition moving, resizing, ... Be aware that all those recommend a proper backup before using them. I personally was lucky and never had a data loss nor on windows neither on linux.

Comment: You have a MBR partitioned disk with a partition inberween the system partition and the unpartitioned space.  You should be able to delete the Recovery partition to accomplish your goals.  I strongly suggest using GPT instead though

Comment: IIRC you also can't extend your boot partition while it's in use, so even if that recovery partition weren't there, you would still need to boot off a different drive first to extend it.

Comment: Whats GPT? I tried gPar.. something. Forgot the name, I tried using a boot image too with no prevail.

Comment: Presumably you used GParted.  It should be able move your recovery partition.  Perhaps read https://askubuntu.com/questions/659797/gparted-cant-move-extended-partition-to-the-right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A volume can only be extended into adjacent free space. You can't extend your C: volume because of the intervening Recovery partition.

If you don't need the Recovery partition, simply delete it, then you will be able to complete the extension of C: without trouble.

If you need the partition, then you should consider using a 3rd party utility to move it. Windows does not provide a way to do this. Be sure to have a backup before making any such changes.